# Multiple Insert in different tables with insert new AI

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP-script in which I can register news users.
Of course I want to insert things like username, password etc. (these values come from the user) but on the other side I want to insert his user_id (new user!) into another table.

**My SQL**

```
$sql =  "
            BEGIN;
                INSERT INTO users (username, password, auth_lvl, realname, usercolor) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$auth_lvl', '$realname', '$usercolor');
                INSERT INTO users_startmodules (user_id, startmodule, enabled) VALUES ('(SELECT MAX(user_id)+1 FROM users)', 'newsmodule', '1');
            COMMIT;
            ";
```

How can I solve this problem and is `BEGIN; ... COMIT;` the right choice when I want to get the query canceled if just one thing didn't work, because I don't want to have just a few entries in the worst case.

Comment: Inserting user provided data directly into your database isn't the best idea no matter what you do. I suggest using MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements. I'm not formilliar with MySQLi myself, but with PDO it's a matter of using `beginTransaction()` / `endTransaction()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to change the type of **user_id** in users table to `auto_increment` with something like this:

```
alter table users alter column user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Now, Assuming that you have escaped the user input data:

```
$query="INSERT INTO users (username, password, auth_lvl, realname, usercolor) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$auth_lvl', '$realname', '$usercolor');"
```

and run that:

```
 $mysqli->query($query);
```

then get the userid with `mysql_insert_id()` function of `MySQL` or alternatively in `PHP`:

```
  $userid=$mysqli->insert_id;
```

and:

```
  $query="INSERT INTO users_startmodules (user_id, startmodule, enabled) VALUES ('$userid', 'newsmodule', '1');";
   $mysqli->query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

To get the id that was just inserted, use `last_insert_id()`.  This function is documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

Next, the answer to your question is to start a transaction.  I would give you the syntax, but it is better for you to read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html) on transactions before you start using them.

The key idea is that a transaction groups data modifications together.  Either all take place or none do.  Along the way, you can use `commit` or `rollback`, depending on whether or not you want to keep the changes or keep none of the changes.